# why dosn't MySQL like the user 'a'@'b' when I just dropped them from mysql.user?

Tags: mysql, createuser

This is what I did.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'matrix'@'%.something.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'weak';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'matrix'@'%.something.com'
mysql> CREATE USER 'foo'@'%.something.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'weak';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

And this is what I end up with:

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------------------+--------------------+
| user             | host               |
+------------------+--------------------+
| auth             | %.something.com    |
| foo              | %.something.com    |
| submit           | %.something.com    |
| testcase         | %.something.com    |
| version          | %.something.com    |
| root             | 127.0.0.1          |
| root             | this.something.com |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost          |
| master           | localhost          |
| root             | localhost          |
+------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

It seems that the issue is that I removed users via a `DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User IN (%s);` to get around the problem that I don't know if the accounts exist.

My (ugly) solution, replace the `DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE...` with:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE dropuserif(u VARCHAR(32), h VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
  DECLARE s INT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO s FROM mysql.user WHERE user = u AND host = h;
  IF s > 0 THEN
    BEGIN
      SET @d = CONCAT("DROP USER '", u, "'@'", h, "';");
      PREPARE stmt_name FROM @d;
      EXECUTE stmt_name;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_name;
    END;
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

A web search for "error 1396" turns up [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28331).

The cause seems to be previously deleted user entries still somehow latent in the database, and blocking the creation of new accounts with the same name.

Try a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` before the first statement and run them again.

Answer (score 0):

look [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28331) for a good start towards this issue

[snark]
Is there a reason you didn't just search for '`mysql ERROR 1396`'?
[/snark]'

Comment: I just did run the search. Without knowing about what Pekka stated. I would have rejected the first half of the first page of results including the link he posted.